# cleveref, ntheorem and lj-igpl

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref, ntheorem

The `cleveref` package doesn't work properly with the `lj-igpl` package.
There are many discussions about `cleveref`, however, none of them solves my problem.
I am using the `ntheorem` package as well, but switching to `amsthm` doesn't help.

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{ntheorem}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}    
\usepackage{lj-igpl}  
\Title{Example}  
 \ShortAuthor{}
 \LongAuthor{}

\begin{document}
\begin{paper}
\begin{lemma}
\label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

By \Cref{lem1}, bla bla.
\end{paper}

\end{document}
```

The result is "By Chapter 1" instead of "By Lemma 1".

If I turn off `ntheorem`, then "Chapter" is replaced by "??".

Also, it doesn't help to load `lj-igpl` before `cleveref`.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. As `lj-igpl.sty` is not available from CTAN, can you add a link to where it can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to download lj-igpl.sty.  The reason that the cross referencing is messed up is because of the passage in lj-igpl.sty reproduced below.  It just messes with latex's theorem numbering mechanisms.  If you can give up on lj-igpl.sty (if need be, submit to a better journal ;-)); otherwise just use \ref.

```
% THEOREM ENVIRONMENTS

% Prevent users from defining new numbering schemes for theorems by
% mapping 
%
%  \newtheorem{1}[2]{3}  to  \newtheorem{1}[thmcount]{3}
%  \newtheorem{1}{2}     to  \newtheorem{1}[thmcount]{3}
%  \newtheorem{1}{2}[3]  to  \newtheorem{1}[thmcount]{3}
%

\@definecounter{thmcount}\@addtoreset{thmcount}{section}
\def\thethmcount{\thesection .\arabic{thmcount}}

\let\@@othm\@othm
\def\@othm#1[#2]#3{%
   % if #1 is already defined, do nothing (but print a warning)
   \@ifundefined{#1}{%
      % if #1 is undefined, do \@othm but force counter to thmcount
      \@@othm{#1}[thmcount]{#3}
   }{\@warning{othm: `#1' already defined; skipping this definition}}}

\def\@xnthm#1#2[#3]{%
   % if already defined, just print a warning
   \@ifundefined{#1}{%
      % if #1 is undefined, do \@othm but force counter to thmcount
      \@@othm{#1}[thmcount]{#2}
   }{\@warning{xnthm: `#1' already defined; skipping this definition}}}

\def\@ynthm#1#2{%
   \@ifundefined{#1}{%
      % if #1 is undefined, do \@othm but force counter to thmcount
      \@@othm{#1}[thmcount]{#2}
   }{\@warning{ynthm: `#1' already defined; skipping this definition}}}
```

Comment: Well, following your advice I am trying another journal: The review of symbolic logic. For this one, I use rsl.cls from here: ftp://ftp.cambridge.org/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/rsl-cls   and a similar problem occurs. I don't find similarities between your snippet from igpl and this cls file. Maybe here something can be done, other than switching to a third journal?